# Inserting Data with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to insert value from html page via nodejs to MySQL. But error occurred as  "Rollno is not defined". I can get the html page but when submitting the value error occurred.

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var sql=require('mysql');

var con=sql.createConnection({...});

app.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html',{'root': __dirname });
})

app.get('/insert',function (req,res){

    var data = {
        Rollno:req.body.Rollno,
        Name:req.body.Name
    };


    con.query("insert into test set ?",data, function (err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send("Value has bee inserted");
    })

})
```

html code page....
    
    
        Index
    
    
        
        Username: 
        Password:

Answer (score 2):

2 suggestions:

1.Enable body-parser:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

2.Make it as post request:

```
app.post('/insert',....)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply raj,  Eventually its work a small changes in that app.use(bodyParser());

Comment: @chozhan Glad to help you..have a happy coding.. Please accept the answer if it really helped you..